# How to integrate your app in Bing "Apps" list

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing

I was watching today's Microsoft's Keynote at CES 2012 and noticed the demonstrator searching for a restaurant in bing.

Once he has finalized the place, he select it and goes to the apps list which provides him with a list of app to which he can transfer the place details, in this OpenTable app and which in turns helps him do the booking.

How can I place my app in that app list? Do I require a special tie-up with Microsoft for this or an API is available for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `Quick Cards` as described in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286420%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). There's more [information here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202957%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) specific to search results and a sample application called `Search Extensibility Sample` on this [sample applications page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28VS.92%29.aspx).

Comment: And note that not all Bing search results are available in all countries (the exact list of markets results work in is included in one of the links keyboardP has provided)

Comment: Thank you.. Much appreciated!! Wish I had searched for the keyword "Extensibility" for this.. :)

Comment: No problem! You can also extend the Picture and Music hubs in a slightly different way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202966%28v=vs.92%29.aspx